# Fresh install of Ubuntu and remove windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 10. Since I never ever use Windows 10, I would like to completely remove Windows 10 and install Ubuntu 16.04. Now there are plenty of websites describing how to install Ubuntu, but I don't know how to remove Windows 10 and use the extra space for Ubuntu. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Would you mind shooting the whole disk for a clean install ?

Comment: @Videonauth No, not at all, I actually expected that that was necessary. I just don't know exactly how to do it.

Comment: @Hunter if you are okay with a clean install, pop in a live USB with 16.04, then during the partition prep, select the option to erase everything.

Comment: @Hunter I thought of posting as an answer, but the installer is self-explanatory on this. You may want to delete the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you dont mind beginning from completely new you can go down the following route:

---

**Phase 1: Preperation**

- Download the disk image of your ubuntu of choice.
- Burn the image to a DVD or Write it bootable on an USB stick.
- Make sure your image works before you continue (this is essential)!

---

**Phase 2 : Cleaning the HDD**

- Boot into your live image and choose to try out
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open a terminal
- Become root by issuing `sudo su` (no password needed on a live CD for root i.e. password is empty)
- Umount your HDD by issuing `umount /dev/sda`
- **(warning youre crossing the point of no return all data will be ireversible destroyed) !!!!**
- Ok to delete you HDD completely issue `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4MB` (let this run for as long it needs, may take a while)

---

**Phase 3:Installing**

- Reboot now on your live CD/USB
- Choose to install
- ?
- Profit!!! (sorry couldnt resist xD)

Comment: IMHO, zeroing out with dd, as a way to delete partitions is ineffective and completely unnecessary. In some cases, it can take hours, ...not cool at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just boot from the Ubuntu installation USB/DVD, and click the Install button, and follow [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop). 
At Installation type, make sure to select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", 
[image]

...then proceed according to the guide.

PS: Backup important files before installing, as the process will delete all data on the HDD.