# How to remove windows 10 and install a fresh Ubuntu server (20.04)

Tags: server, system-installation, 20.04, ssd

I would like some help with the installation of **Ubuntu Server**, the installer seems pretty self-explanatory alongside video guides. However without sounding too repetitive like this similar question: [Fresh install of Ubuntu and remove windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760233/fresh-install-of-ubuntu-and-remove-windows-10)

I have gotten to the part of the installer which asked for Guided Storage configuration (I expected to see a file system setup page):

- However, I get the following message (Block probing did not discover any disk big enough to support guided storage configuration. Manual configuration may still be possible) where others are usually directed to a screen (file system setup) letting them choose to "pick the entire disk" etc.
- I am then redirected to the storage configuration screen but my local disk has no available space. This is because this disk is running windows 10, I do not wish to partition the disk but rather clean this SSD to dedicate it for **Ubuntu Server**.
- Any other actions I perform on this page will generate a crash report and the done option is disabled.

I was under the impression that the installer would give me an option to create a fresh Ubuntu server install however I am not seeing this option anywhere.

I see that an option will be to clear the SSD with other methods but I would like to know what would be my best course of action here to get a fresh installation of Ubuntu Server while also removing the previous OS it is running (Windows 10).

Update: I have performed a secure erase on the SSD in hope that this will no longer be an issue however I am still faced with the same problem, below are screenshots of what I am encountering (screenshots begin after the configure Ubuntu archine mirror window which is when I encounter the issue):

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB5aB.jpg

Here are also screenshots of my BIOS' boot settings and the available boot options:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATVSB.jpg

Comment: I think in this case few good quality photos of the relevant screens cold help us to guide you! Yesterday I've done exactly the same - made fresh installation of Ubuntu Server 20.04 over Windows 10 on SSD, but can't remember such case.

Comment: @pa4080 I have updated the post with screenshots, they were too big to post directly please use the link provided. Thank you for your response!

Comment: I'm not sure this could be the reason, but: If the previous OS was installed in EFI mode and you are booting the installation in Legacy mode (and vice versa) - it is a possible trouble maker. Please verify the available options in your BIOS / UEFI and the available boot options in order to eliminate (or confirm) this assumption.

Comment: @pa4080 This is the screenshot of the bootable device and the mode. If I am not mistaking the installer is booting on UEFI and the mode is also UEFI. Thank you for your help! https://imgur.com/a/yW2XoYB

Comment: Maybe the disk is in RAID mode instead of AHCI?

Comment: @ubfan1 Thank you! I set up a new USB installer just to rule out any possibilities of having a bad installer. I had the same problem with the new USB, however, after checking the disk mode it was not in AHCI mode after switching it over to AHCI mode the installer ran just as expected! Thank you everyone for your help and contribution!

PS Please let me know how to mark this question as answered.

Comment: You need an answer first;^D  (which I jsut added).  Click on the accept button on the answer will mark the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the BIOS/UEFI settings, change the disk mode from RAID to to AHCI, and the installer should run.  In the case of wanting to dual boot with Windows, ensure that the AHCI drivers for Windows have been downloaded before you change the disk mode.